# Опечатка во всплывающем сообщении

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, выборы

Опечатка во всплывающем сообщении после голосования на выборах модератора: в местоимении "мы" - должно быть "вы":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Напоминаем, что до окончания выборов **мы** можете изменить свои
>   голоса.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/vote-moderator/ - в этом скрипте ошибка